# Android exceptions claim missing API key in device install, but works on emulator #appcelerator

Tags: api, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

My app builds and installs in android emulator, but errors out during install/launch on my Sammy S5. The error seems to be related to the google maps API key which is in my tiapp.xml. The section in question is:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
        <manifest>
            <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
            <!-- Allows the API to download data from Google Map servers -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <!-- Allows the API to cache data -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <!-- Use GPS for device location -->
            <!-- Use Wi-Fi or mobile connection for device location -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
            <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
            <!-- Specify OpenGL ES 2.0 as a requirement -->    
            <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="com.appcelerator.sample.mapping.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
            <permission android:name="com.appcelerator.sample.mapping.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
            <application>
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBNHcyplkOpzO_...remainder redacted"/>
                </application>
                <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

As you can see, the API key is clear and obvious and works in the emulator, but the packaged and signed apk installs and flames out with "Ti Application" errors and "Androd Runtime" errors in my Appcelerator console

```
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [1193,2581] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml; Titanium 5.1.2,2015/12/16 19:00,ca822b2
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears your device/target is requiring a new key name. Try changing your key from `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` to `com.google.android.geo.v2.API_KEY`.  Google changed the key from `maps` to `geo` to support multiple APIs.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en):

> For backwards compatibility, the API also supports the name com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY. This legacy name allows authentication to the Android Maps API v2 only. An application can specify only one of the API key metadata names. If both are specified, the API throws an exception.

Comment: hmmm. I would have thought the appcelerator docs would be up to date, but even with your suggestions the same error was thrown in the appcelerator console. The app installs then crashes on launch with the same error, complaining about the API key. I tried ... geo.API_KEY as the google page you link suggested, and I also tried the ...geo.v2.API_KEY as you suggested. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Does the error looks like this

```
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [735,735] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gsl.TracKm/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml; Titanium 5.1.1,2015/11/24 11:07,e46100b
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gsl.TracKm/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

If so, Try to keep one application tag in the Android manafest in ti.app xml file. Like this

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
          <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBNHcyplkOpzO_...remainder redacted"/>
</application>
```

This is working on device. I test with keeping one application tag and the exception was gone.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but w/o any difference. I also tried variants of your suggestion with deltas based on change suggested by tzmartins above, without any improvement.

Comment: did you set the exact API key from google project in         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/> ?